# Easy way to Get JSON From URL

Tags: java, android, json

I want get JSON from URL address, this simple JSON in URL

```
 [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "دانیال",
    "sex": "male",
    "reshte": "تجربی",
    "rotbe": "3000+",
    "image": "https://xxxxxx.png",
    "telegram": "danyall1377",
    "instagram": "danyall1377",
    "phone": "09xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "دانیال",
    "sex": "male",
    "reshte": "تجربی",
    "rotbe": "3000+",
    "image": "xxxxxxxxx.png",
    "telegram": "dadddddd",
    "instagram": "ddddddd",
    "phone": "091xxxxxxx"
  }
]
```

Is there easy way for do that?

Comment: NetworkOnMailThreadEception Problem How I Fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use third party libraries like volley, retrofit....
for example with volley you should make a JsonArrayRequest to the server and parse it.

[Farsi resource](http://www.wiadevelopers.com/downloads/%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B7-%D8%B3%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-volley/)

[English resource](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

and this is a basic request:

```
JsonArrayRequest jarr = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            try{

                for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                    JSONObject job = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = job.getString("name");

                }

            } catch (Exception e){


            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jarr);
```

Answer (score -1):

For getting data from server using retrofit library: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Retrofit good example:
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

For directly making classes of JSON reponse use:
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Please don't copy-paste the links here. instead, try to demonstrate how answer should be.(Preferably in code) [**How do I write a good answer?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)